# Paid membership for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, membership

I'm trying to find the way to do paid memberships in a Drupal site, for example, access some content when I pay some membership. I have read a lot but most of the example are for Drupal 6 or using moneyscripts.net. Also I have read some tutorials about ubercart, uc_recurring, etc but none of them work well.

Is there some way to add paid memberships in Drupal 7? Maybe someone can give me some direction, thread, tutorial, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the Drupal forums and they helped me with the solution, here is the thread: http://drupal.org/node/1607152 and here you can find the solution: http://drupal.org/node/1312418

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution to this. [Commerce subscription products](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_sp) looks like the best option but I am still researching options and haven't tested this solution yet due to some limitations:

- This modules does not implement a recurrent payment solution and automated subscription renewals. Though this could be integrated via add-on modules.
- The module provides only one kind of subscriptions on a site. If multiple subscription types are needed, the module and its configuration could be theoretically cloned (and renamed) though.

Comment: Hi, please the comment above, hope it can help you.